# Creating new channels after RabbitMQ connection was blocked

Tags: rabbitmq, .net-4.8, rabbitmq.client

I have a very basic demo application for testing the RabbitMQ blocking behaviour. I use RabbitMQ 3.10.6 with the .NET library RabbitMQ.Client 6.2.4 in .NET Framework 4.8.

The disk is filled until the configured threshold in the RabbitMQ config file is exceeded. The connection state is "blocking".

I queue a message this way:
AMQP properties are added to the message using `channel.CreateBasicProperties()` with `Persistent = true`. It is then queued:

```
sendChannel.BasicPublish("", "sendQueueName", amqpProperties, someBytes);
sendChannel.WaitForConfirmsOrDie(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

WaitForConfirmsOrDie() closes the underlying channel when the broker is blocking or blocked. Because this is the case the channel is closed and I need to create a new one if I want to queue messages again.

The connection state is "blocked".

First example: I catch the TimeoutException that is thrown, remove the resource alarm by providing enough disk space and create a new channel in the catch block. This works.

Second example: I catch the TimeoutException that is thrown but do nothing in the catch block. I remove the resource alarm by providing enough disk space and wait for the `ConnectionUnblocked` event to be fired. In here I create a new channel. But here it doesn't work. I get a TimeoutException.

Why can't I create any more channels outside the catch block once the connection was blocked?

The connection is created using `ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()` and uses `AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true` (although this doesn't seem to make any difference).

A channel is created using `Connection.CreateModel()`.

Comment: Hello, I maintain the .NET client library. The best way to get assistance is to share the code you're using via a github/gitlab repository, as well as explicit instructions on how to reproduce the issue. That way I don't have to guess and can spend time on the actual problem at hand. Please start a new discussion here and I will see it: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/discussions

Comment: Thank you very much. See here: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/discussions/1255